# Consoling shallow(<component />) results in ShallowWrapper {}

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

this is my collegeName.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import PersonalProfile from '../../../components/Profile/Tabs/Personal';
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import configureStore from "../../../redux/configureStore";
import { fetchData, mutateData } from "../../../utils/graphqlUtility";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

const store = configureStore();
//const store = mockStore({});

jest.mock('../../../utils/graphqlUtility', () => {
  return {
    A:"hihihi"
  };
});

describe('Personal Profile', () => {
  test('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersonalProfile />
      </Provider>
    );
    console.log(wrapper)
    let tree = wrapper.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    //<div className="row pad"></div>
    //expect(wrapper.contains(<label>Bond Expiration Date</label>)).to.equal(true);
    //const paragraph = wrapper.find('div')
    //console.log("dsdsds",paragraph)
    //expect(paragraph).toHaveLength(1)
  });
});
```

In this file, I am shallowing personalprofile component and this personal profile component calls some methods of graphqlutility file so I mocked graphqlutility file. And then while I am consoling the wrapper its showing me like this in console `ShallowWrapper {}`.I don't know why the console is showing empty?
[image]

I have also attached the screenshot of the console. Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `enzyme`'s `debug()` function:

```
console.log(wrapper.debug());
```

Comment: this helped a lot. Thanks!